# HTML CSS JS - OnClick working on just 1 div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to shrink right side div when left navigation menu is open. Here is my code example,

HTML :

```
<div id="home" class="full"><p>Home</p></div>
<div id="about" class="full"><p>About</p></div>
<div id="portfolio" class="full"><p>Portfolio</p></div>
<div id="skills" class="full"><p>Skills</p></div>
<div id="contact" class="full"><p>Contact</p></div>
```

Css :

```
.full{height: 100vh;color: #fff;}
.PageShrink{margin-left: 30vh;}
```

JS:

```
const fullPage = document.querySelector('.full');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!menuOpen) {
    fullPage.classList.add('PageShrink');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    fullPage.classList.remove('PageShrink');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

The issue is, when I click on menuBtn to slide in from left, Home shrinks 30vh according to code, but after that if I click on About,portfolio etc its not shrinking even though they have same class. Not sure whats wrong but it just works on 1st div i.e, home.

Please assist,
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `querySelector` only selects the first element. You have to use `querySelectorAll` and cycle through all elements with that class

Comment: You have only selected the first element with `full` class and not all. Use `querySelectorAll` for your use-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is within the JS. You use `querySelector` which only targets the first element with that class. So you have to use `querySelectorAll`. However this only gives you an array of all elements and the JS change is only applied to the first element still. So you need to cycle through all elements with that class by using: `fullPage.forEach(el => el.classList.add('PageShrink'));`

```
const fullPage = document.querySelectorAll('.full');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!menuOpen) {
    fullPage.forEach(el => el.classList.add('PageShrink'));
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    fullPage.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('PageShrink'));
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

For demonstration and testing:

```js
function caseA() {
  document.querySelector(".test").style.color = "red";
}

function caseB() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".test").style.color = "green";
}

function caseC() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".test").forEach(el => el.style.color = "blue");
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
  <li class="test">Test</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="caseA()">querySelector</button>
<button onclick="caseB()">querySelectorAll</button>
<button onclick="caseC()">querySelectorAll + forEach</button>
```

You see that "Case A" is onyl targetign the first element. "Case B" will cause an error as `querySelectorAll` returns an array of elements not an element itself. If you use `forEach` you can apply your JS comamnd to all the elements as it cycles through the array and applies it to every element of the array.

Comment: Baaammm!!! Man you are a genius. Its working now. Thanks a bunch!